# Assign coordinate to dimension in xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

Suppose I have the following DataSet:

```
>>> coords = {"coords": ("x", [10, 20, 30, 40])}
>>> dset = xr.Dataset(coords=coords)
>>> dset
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 4)
Coordinates:
    coords   (x) int64 10 20 30 40
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

How can I modify the dataset such that xarray knows to assign 'coords' to the dimension 'x'? I.e. I do not want 'x' to be a dimension without coordinates, the coordinates are supposed to be 'coords'.

I'd like to know how to achieve this in these two ways:

1. By modifying how the dataset is created
2. By post-hoc "fixing" the existing dataset

Comment: do you want your coordinate to be called `x` or `coords`? why do you have two different names in there?

Answer (score 0):

xarray has concepts of both `dimensions` and `coordinates`. Dimensions are the names assigned to each array axis. Coordinates define labels along the axis.

You've defined the coordinate `coords`, indexed by dimension `x`. The `coords` coordinate has labels `[10, 20, 30, 40]` along dimension `x`. You never define labels for dimension `x` though.

What you probably mean is to have a coordinate `x` which provides labels for dimension `x`:

```py
In [2]: coords = {"x": ("x", [10, 20, 30, 40])}
   ...: ds = xr.Dataset(coords=coords)
   ...: ds
Out[2]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 4)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 10 20 30 40
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

See the [xarray docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html) and the [xarray tutorial](https://tutorial.xarray.dev/fundamentals/01_datastructures.html)  sections on Data Structures for more info.

Comment: So are you saying that they must have the same name in order for xarray to associate the coordinate labels with a certain dimension? I can't just tell it how to match them up?

Comment: you don't have to have a coordinate (set of labels) for each dimension. but if they don't have the same name, then you will have a dimension without coordinates. In your question, you have the dimension `x`, with no coordinate labels, and the coordinate `coords`, with dimensions `(x, )`. They are associated, but yeah they must have the same name if you want them to be the labels for the dimension. Otherwise, they're just a set of non-dimension coordinates.

Comment: note that "dimension without coordinates" doesn't mean "there are no coordinates associated with this dimension". it means "this dimension does not have labels explicitly assigned to it." there can be non-dimension coords which have x as the dimension, but that's different than having coordinates explicitly labeling x. non-dimension coords are more like extra metadata indexed by x; but a coord x defines the actual levels of x and do hold a special significance for selection/indexing, etc

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah I wanted to use the coordinates for selection/indexing, but I also didn't want to give them the same name. In my case I have a "station" dimension, which is used by various coordinate, indeed like extra metadata (station_id, station_name, etc). But I then wanted to be able to index other datasets using the 'station' dimension using e.g. station_name. But I guess I can't do that without explicitly matching up the names, which seems a shame. I guess I'll just stick with less direct selection methods.

Comment: `station_id` seems like a perfectly good dimension to use. there are significant advantages to having labels/coordinates associated with a dimension, so I'd strongly advise you to just pick one of those metadata fields and use it as a unique dimension label, and name your dimension the same thing. you could of course rename "station_id" to just be "station". but yes, they do need to have the same name.